# Java Comparator Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, arrays, class, comparator

I want to sort an `array` of 2 dimensional arrays in Java according to some rules, let's say the distance from the origin. I saw several ways of doing it using `Arrays.sort()`:

1) `Arrays.sort(points, Comparator.comparing(p -> p[0]*p[0] + p[1]*p[1]));`

2) `Arrays.sort(points, (p1, p2) -> p1[0]*p1[0] + p1[1]*p1[1] - p2[0]*p2[0] - p2[1]*p2[1]);`

3) Defining the `class`:

```
class Point implements Comparable<Point>{
     // class variables, constructor
     public int compareTo(Point p) {
         return (x*x + y*y).compareTo(p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y);
     }
}
```

An array `pts` of type `Points` is then created and `Arrays.sort(pts)` is used. My question is regarding **1)** and **2)**: I see the difference between the but I do not understand when to use one and when to use the other and what exactly `Comparator.comparing()` is doing. Why is the first solution carrying the information just with one point while the second need two points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Comparator.comparing` is implemented as follows:

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

i.e. it uses the `Function` you pass to it in order to transform each of the compared elements into a `Comparable`, and then uses the `Comparable`'s `compareTo` method.

When you are passing the function `p -> p[0]*p[0] + p[1]*p[1]`, you are converting each point to its sum of squares. Then, when the `Comparator` needs to compare two points, it compares the sum of squares of the two points, which is almost equivalent to computing the difference of the sums of squares of the two points (it's not exactly equivalent, since comparing two numbers by computing their difference can produce wrong output in case of numeric overflow).

That's exactly what your second `Comparator` - `(p1, p2) -> p1[0]*p1[0] + p1[1]*p1[1] - p2[0]*p2[0] - p2[1]*p2[1]` - does,

since `p1[0]*p1[0] + p1[1]*p1[1] - p2[0]*p2[0] - p2[1]*p2[1] == 
     (p1[0]*p1[0] + p1[1]*p1[1]) - (p2[0]*p2[0] + p2[1]*p2[1])`.

Using `Comparator.comparing()` is safer, since it compares the sums of squares of the two points without computing their difference. It uses `Double`'s `compareTo()` instead (assuming the coordinates of your points are `Double` or `double`).

In other words, the first alternative uses a `Function` that needs just one point since this function tells `Comprator.comparing` how to transform each of the 2 points.

On the other hand, the second alternative accepts 2 points (which are the required arguments of the `Comparator.compare()` method) and determines the relative order of these 2 points.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Comparator.comparing()` you're saying "I want to use this property when comparing objects of this class". The property needs to be `Comparable`, so you see it used often with numeric properties, for example: `Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getId)` returns a `Comparator` with the logic "compare MyObjects by using their numeric id".

With `(p1, p2) ->` you're doing more work yourself. You're given 2 objects, and you need to return -1, 0 or +1 depending on whether `p1` is is lesser, equal or greater to `p2`. This allows for more complex logic, but is more verbose and less readable than the first option if you're sorting based on one or a few properties.

Lastly you're making the class itself implement `Comparable`. This is usually referred to as the natural ordering. A `Point` doesn't really have a **natural** ordering like for example numbers, so creating a `compareTo` method is not something I'd advise.

Answer (score 1):

In 2) one has to make a comparison between both operands of the comparison with respect to some function. In 1) one just specifies the one function that delivers the value to be compared. Besides `comparing` there also is for numerical values (like here) `comparingInt, comparingLong, comparingDouble`.

So 1) is the simplest to read.

For points with doubles the hypotenuse can be used, the actual distance to the origin

```
Arrays.sort(points, Comparator.comparingDouble(p -> Math.hypot(p[0], p[1]));
```

**And then the bad news:**

Two dimensional distance sorting *does not give a sequential order*.
Hence sorting will not work between two elements. You can only sort with respect to one fixed point. Say rank the array points with respect to some fixed point.
Here you take the distance to the origin (0, 0).